# Good Junit testing for create a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, junit, jtable

I'm very new at JUnit testing and I am trying to create some tests for creating a JTable. I wonder if anyone can guide me through some basic tests to create a JTable?

Much Appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that you'd specifically test the creation of the table but rather the data that you're populating it with. (Not unless you're creating a number of tables at run-time)

For example, say you have two rows of data you want to put into the table.

```
// Given
JTable table = new JTable()
//populate data etc.

//When
int rowCount = table.getRows() etc.

//Then
assertEquals(2, rowCount);
```

Keep in mind what you're actually testing. Be careful not to go off on tangents and start testing things that don't need to be/not meant to be tested.